# xpath get matches in sublist

Tags: xslt, xpath

I've got the following xml:

```
    <vo class="GroupEntry" buildByAlias="true">
        <objectClass name="groupOfNames"/>
        <field name="commonName"          nameLDAP="cn"          type="String"/>
        <field name="descriptione"         nameLDAP="description"          type="String"/>
        <field name="member"              nameLDAP="member"               type="String[]"/>
    </vo>
    <update method="addMember" modificationMode="ADD_ATTRIBUTE">
        <input>
            <field name="member"/>        
            <field name="description"/>        
        </input>
    </update>
```

I'm using XSLT to transform it, and I'm need, for each update, to get the fields in the vo that correspond to the field defined in the input. It would be something like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="fields" select="vo/field" />
<xsl:for-each select="update">
    <xsl:variable name='fieldsForInput' select = "$fields[@name]=input/fields[@name]"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$fieldsForInput">
       <xsl:value-of select="@type"/> <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
    <xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

But it doesn't found anything. Any ideas?

Thanks

JL

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for two different, complete, short and easy solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the shown fragments it's difficult helping you and understadning what you want. However your case seems perfect for using `xsl:key`.

For example, if you create a key at the beginning of the transform like this:

```
<xsl:key name="fields" match="vo/field" use="@name"/>
```

You can use it inside your matching template as follows:

```
        <xsl:for-each select="update/input">
            <xsl:copy-of select="key('fields',current()/field/@name)"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

I would not use a `xsl:foreach` anyway. But it's hard to give you a complete solution if you provide only fragments. Also is not clear if you want just match or replace `field`.

---

Example showing how to get the field `name/type` for each `update/input/field`.

**XSLT 1.0** tested with **Saxon 6.5.5**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="fields" match="vo/field" use="@name"/>

 <xsl:template match="/root">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="update"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="update">
     <xsl:value-of select="concat('-',@method,'&#xA;')"/>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="input/field"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="input/field">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('--',@name,' ',key('fields',@name)/@type,'&#xA;')"/>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied on:

```
<root>
    <vo class="GroupEntry" buildByAlias="true">
        <objectClass name="groupOfNames"/>
        <field name="commonName"          nameLDAP="cn"          type="String"/>
        <field name="description"         nameLDAP="description"          type="String"/>
        <field name="member"              nameLDAP="member"               type="String[]"/>
    </vo>
    <update method="addMember" modificationMode="ADD_ATTRIBUTE">
        <input>
            <field name="member"/>        
            <field name="description"/>        
        </input>
    </update>
        <update method="deleteMember" modificationMode="DELETE_ATTRIBUTE">
        <input>
            <field name="member"/>        
            <field name="description"/>        
        </input>
    </update>
</root>
```

Produces:

```
-addMember
--member String[]
--description String
-deleteMember
--member String[]
--description String
```

Comment: Well, I just wat to match field. The thing is that I need for each field defined in the update/input, the matching field in the vo, so I don't need to define the type and nameLDAP in the input, just make a reference in the input, and get the values from the vo.

Comment: I just edited the question in order to clarify what I need exactly.

Comment: If you want to clarify what you need, you should provide an XML sample of your output. Since you have accepted the answer I assume you are done now. Are you?

Comment: I've extended the answer with something that might be closer to what you require.

Comment: Note that you had a misspelling in your `vo/field/@name` for description. I've changed in the input document `descriptione` to `description`.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions:

**Solution1** (no keys):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match=
  "vo/field[@name=../../update/*/*/@name]">

  <xsl:value-of select="concat(@name,' ',@type,'&#xA;')"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML document** (corrected to be made well-formed):

```
<t>
    <vo class="GroupEntry" buildByAlias="true">
        <objectClass name="groupOfNames"/>
        <field name="commonName" nameLDAP="cn" type="String"/>
        <field name="description" nameLDAP="description" type="String"/>
        <field name="member" nameLDAP="member" type="String[]"/>
    </vo>
    <update method="addMember" modificationMode="ADD_ATTRIBUTE">
        <input>
            <field name="member"/>
            <field name="description"/>
        </input>
    </update>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
description String
member String[]
```

**Solution2** (using a key):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kFieldByName" match="vo/field"
  use="@name"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="selected" select=
    "key('kFieldByName', update/*/*/@name)"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="vo/field" mode="selected">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(@name,' ',@type,'&#xA;')"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the same XML document (above), the same correct result is produced**:

```
description String
member String[]
```